# Passing video id to Brightcove HTML5 player

Tags: jquery, brightcove

I'm trying to pass a data-video-id dynamically based on the link the user clicks to a Brightcove HTML5 player. I'm trying to use jQuery but having trouble finding the right way to insert the variable inside the data-video-id tag within the video tag. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
    JS:
            function sendVal(brightcoveId) {
                var myId = brightcoveId;
                $("#video_1").html('data-video-id=" + (myId) + "' );
            }
        </script>  

 HTML: 
<video 
        id="video_1"
        data-account="54541216001" 
        data-player="a53534534-7a60-5f3a-9152-989ccbbf6112" 
        data-embed="default" 
        class="video-js" 
        controls 
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px;"></video>
```

Comment: http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/brightcove-player/samples/dynamically-change-video.html?_ga=1.49675941.2034721298.1466615818

Answer (score 0):

OK - found a workaround that Brightcove recommends:

```
// Initialise player
    var brightcovePlayer;
    // When the player's ready, let's get started
    videojs("video_1").ready(function(){
        brightcovePlayer = this;
    });
    function changeVideo(brightcoveId){
        brightcovePlayer.catalog.getVideo(brightcoveId, function(error, video) { 
            // Load the video
            brightcovePlayer.catalog.load(video);
            // Play the video
            brightcovePlayer.play();
        })
    }
```